# Finding an angle involving two triangles inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

[image]

Since $\overline{OA} \parallel \overline{BC}$, we have that
So I know that $\angle COA=\angle BCO=40^\circ$. I'm trying to figure out how to make use of the facts that these triangles are inscribed in circles... help appreciated!

Comment: Use the fact that $\angle COA \cong 2 \angle CBA$.

Comment: $\angle{ABC}=\dfrac12\angle{COA}=20^{\circ}$ Then $\angle{ODA}=120^{\circ}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\angle O =\angle OCB = 40^°$ (alternate interior angles, $OA \parallel BC$)

$\angle B =\frac{\angle O}{2} = 20^°$ ($\angle$ of center=2$\angle$ circumference subtended same segment)

$\angle ODA=120^°$(sum of $\angle$ 's in a $\triangle$)

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\angle OAD=\angle{ABC}=\dfrac12\angle{AOC}=20^{\circ}$$
because of [Angle at the Centre Is Twice the Angle at the Circumference](https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/arcs-and-subtended-angles/).

So, in $\Delta ODA$, we have
$$\angle AOC=40^\circ\\\angle OAD=20^\circ$$
So,
$$\angle ODA=180^\circ-40^\circ-20^\circ=120^\circ$$